# Detecting the end of asyncExecute

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i use these codes for planning;
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan plan;
kPyGlobals.move_group_end->setJointValueTarget( goals );
kPyGlobals.move_group_end->plan( plan );
kPyGlobals.move_group_end->asyncExecute( plan );

how can i detect execution still running ?

how can i detect robotic-arm ready for plan ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403238/detecting-the-end-of-asyncexecute./) by [omeranar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/45833/omeranar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Several approaches are discussed in #q402633.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1